# Google Spreadsheets Formula to sum value if date falls in month and year

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

There a so many topics about Excel and how to Sum Value if date falls in particular month, but none of them helped me out with google spreadsheets.

Tryed out Excel "kind of formulars" but you can't use them in google spreadsheets:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A6,"MONTH(A2:A6)=1",B2:B6)
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH($A$1:$A$10)=E1)+0;$B$1:$B$10)
```

Because there you can't get an array with `=MONTH(A2:A5)`.

You can use it as `=Month(A2)` (A2 = "01.09.2017") and you get `1`

## Example

I want the `value` from the "Amount Column" from month `june & year 2016`

```
Date        Amount

01.05.2016   20,00€
24.05.2016   25,00€
03.06.2016   10,00€ 
13.06.2016   10,00€
30.06.2016   10,00€
05.01.2017   50,00€
```

Manually it would be `SUM(B4:B6)` to get `30,00€` & `SUM(B7)` to get `50,00€` for year 2017

---

What can I do to solve this problems? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to do this, was by creating an extra area on my spreadsheet to define my searches and use these in an ArrayFormula function.

Using =ArrayFormula(sumifs(B$2:B,month(A$2:A),G4,year(A$2:A),F4))

I reference the Year in Cell G4 and the month in F4.

For the best example of a use case you can look at the shared file.

You can find the example of my solution here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11_GCJBr2BZ2zFBDJj8I6iizD08y6fEmwZiPQjshNa7w/edit?usp=sharing It's not perfect, but I hope it helps you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please ensure your answer is useful when the linked page becomes unavailable in the future. E.g. quote the relevant parts of the linked page **inside your post**.